# How to handle hundreds of sequential APIs in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rest, pdf

I have a situation where I need to generate a report using hundreds of APIs.Now there are some cases when an API depends on another.

I am planning to move independent APIs to be processed via rails services as background jobs.But still need to wait for APIs responses and then generating a page.

Let me know best possible ways of doing it (need to decrease loading time)

Comment: Make it asynchronous; load each section of the page via AJAX. Maybe use polling or websockets if some APIs take a *long* time to respond. And implement cacheing if possible. Without more information (e.g. **what have you tried so far?**), that's pretty much the only answer anyone can give you.

Comment: I'm also a bit confused what you're doing here. You mention "decreasing the loading time", yet this is a PDF generation happening via background jobs?? Are you just asking "how can I make the PDF generate faster"? Well to answer that, we'd **definitely** need to see your code!!

Comment: try this https://coderwall.com/p/5cafjw/1600-faster-app-requests-with-rails-on-heroku

Comment: Yes @TomLord I am asking this for pdf generation process

Comment: @Jaswinder I cannot really suggest how to speed up code that you haven't shown me.

Comment: I am just looking for generic solutions to stream pdf pages asynchronously.Its not a web page where I can make async AJAX calls. I am using a library wicked_pdf to convert the whole html into strings for pdf and it will show pdf only when all pages are convert to pdf object to render

Answer (score 0):

wicked_pdf is nothing more than a wrapper; it is essentially a `system()` call to execute`wkhtmltopdf`as an operating system command.  Every time it executes, it must: 1. fork a new shell process with an environment, 2. execute `wkhtmltopdf` in that shell, 3. slurp in the output and re-present it to Rails. This means it is necessarily both synchronous and horribly inefficient.

You will be better off using the `prawn` gem to generate PDF directly, avoiding all that overhead.  If you really must do it, Rails is thread-safe so you can use  `futures` in the `concurrent-ruby` gem to perform concurrent requests, and block until they all finish.